# Is there a virtual/dummy IMAQ camera for LabVIEW?

Tags: image-processing, webcam, labview, hardware-interface

I'm writing LabVIEW software that grabs images from an IMAQ compatible GigE camera.

The problem: This is a collaborative project, so I only have intermittent access to the actual camera.I'd like to be able to keep developing this software even when the camera isn't present.

Is there a simple/fast way to create a virtual or dummy IMAQ camera in software? Ideally I'd like the dummy camera grab frames from an AVI or a stack of JPEG's. Something like this must exist, I just can't find it on Google.

I'm looking for something that won't take very long (e.g.< 2 hours effort) and that is abstracted away through the standard LabVIEW IMAQ interface, so that my software won't know or care whether its dealing with a dummy camera or an actual camera.

Comment: Can you update this question, no solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this method using LabVIEW classes:
[Hardware Emulation Using LabVIEW Classes](http://vishots.com/hardware-emulation-using-labview-classes/)

Comment: Thanks. This would work, but it isn't really ideal. To do harware emulation using classes I would basically have to write wrappers around each of the IMAQ functions. This seems a bit awkward because the IMAQ framework is already designed as an abstraction layer (it works regardless of specific camera). Ideally  somewhere someone has a dummy camera that fits into the IMAQ framework.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the IMAQdx driver, you might consider just buying a cheap USB webcam for $10.

Answer (score 2):

Use the IMAQdx driver (assuming you have it), and then insert the Vision Acquisition Express VI, and you can choose AVIs or even pics as a source.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: [GigESim](http://www.ab-soft.com/gigesim.php) is a camera emulation software. Unfortunately it is proprietary and too expensive (>$500) for my own needs, but perhaps others will find this link useful.

Anyone know of a viable Open Source alternative?

Answer (score 0):

There's an [IP Camera emulator project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipcameraemu/) that emulates IP camera with python. I haven't used it myself so i don't know if it can be used by IMAQ.

Let us know if it's good for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is really old, but hopefully this answer helps someone out.

IMAQdx also works with Windows DirectShow devices.  While normally these are actual physical capture devices (think USB Webcams), there is no necessity that they have to be.

There are a few different pre-made options available on the web.  I found using [Open Broadcaster Studio](https://obsproject.com/) and this [Virtual Cam plugin](https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-virtual-cam) to be easy enough.  Basically:

1. Download and install both.
2. Load your media sources in the sources list.
3. Enable the VirtualCam stream (*Tools* > *VirtualCam*).  Press Start.